# Flask html template not executing JavaScript, or, the template is not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2, html-rendering

I have my main route which returns `index.html` with no issues.

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
########################################
# block of logic code                  #
########################################
return render_template("index.html")
```

`index.html` has a button, when clicked, does a bunch of stuff and is then successfully routed to

```
@app.route("/edit", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit():
########################################
# block of logic code                  #
########################################
return render_template("successful_save_alert.html")
```

The block of code is successfully executed, however the issue lies on this last `return render_template("successful_save_alert.html")`.
I have followed it with the debugger. It seems to be rendering (debugger enters the `html`), however the JavaScript inside `successful_save_alert.html` is not being executed.

Here is `successful_save_alert.html`

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block script %}
<script>
    alert("Save successful!");
    console.log("alert");
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ########################################
        # block of HTML.                       #
        ########################################
        {% block script %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="static/edit.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The other thing I noticed is, in the Chrome inspect view, the `successful_save_alert.html` is not appearing in the Sources tab. Which is weird because the debugger seems to show it is rendering however it is not rendering in the browser.

My file structure is:

```
├── app.py
├── database.db
├── static
│   ├── edit.js
│   └── styles.css
└── templates
    ├── index.html
    └── successful_save_alert.html
```

Additionally, here are my flask configurations (which I have attempted to remove to see if this fixes the issue)

```
# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
```

Things I have tried:

1. A debugger shows html is "rendering" (i.e. it successfully steps through `successful_save_alert.html`
2. Sources tab in chrome does not show `successful_save_alert.html`
3. File structure is correct
4. Redirecting to a new route e.g. `@app.route("/successful_save_alert.html, methods=["GET", "POST"])` and then rendering the `html` from here, but no luck...
5. I even tried creating a separate JS in the static folder and triggering this from `successful_save_alert.html` however that did not work. Hence why I think the issue may lie in the `html` not being rendered and returned.
6. Removed flask configurations

**My ultimate goal**: render `successful_save_alert.html` from the `@app.route("/edit")...` route and have the JS code be executed.
To replicate full code, refer to [GitHub](https://github.com/kirby-jack/web-app-manually-edit-sqllite3db)

Comment: i cant reproduce this

Answer (score 1):

Okay I worked it out. My understanding of `fetch API` is limited so I need to read up on why this was the case. But here is the resolution.

My button was redirecting to the `"\edit"` route with the `fetch API`. However, I did not handle `fetch`'s returned `Promise` value.

What I needed to do was, if the `fetch` was successful, then redirect to another route with `window.location.href = '/edit';`

For the purposes of this button my final JS `fetch` code looks like

```
    // Send JSON dict to flask 
    const fetchPromise = fetch("/edit", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(JSONDict)
    });

    fetchPromise
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
            }
            else {
                alert("Save successful!")
                window.location.href = '/';
            }

        })
```